# Cant echo Session user php

Tags: php, sql, session, authentication

The if is working but the printed username is "username" and it should be the real username that in this case is "teste".
maybe i need a variable or something to display it after but I'm not getting there :s

This is my Session starter code :

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();
$host="localhost"; // Nome do Host
$username="segu24img"; // Mysql username 
$password="desny"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="segurao_imagem"; // Nome base de dados
$tbl_name="users"; // Nome da tabela

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $username and $password, table row must be 1 row

if($count==1){

// Register $username, $password and redirect to file "login_success.php"
$_SESSION['username'] = 'username';
//session_register("username");
$_SESSION['password'] = 'password';
//session_register("password");
header("location:login_sucess.php");
}
else {
echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
?>
```

Im using this code to display the username of session :

```
<?php 

            if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){ ?>

              </p>

              <p>Bem Vindo<u><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></u>- <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>

<?php } else{ ?>

    <p><a href="#login-box" class="login-window">Login</a></p>

<?php } ?></p>
```

Comment: what do you get when you print_r($_SESSION) ?

Comment: what do you get? an error? a warning?

Comment: also it might be wise to remove your mysql username/password :)

Comment: It just displays  = username instead of the real username it should

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assigning the literal word `username` here:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = 'username';
```

so why should anything else EVER get displayed? Perhaps you should be using

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
                        ^^^^^^^^^
```

ditto for the password field. And as a general tip, you should **NOT** be storing the password in the session.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `$_SESSION['username']` equal to the literal string 'username'. It should be `$_SESSION['username'] = $username`.

UPDATE: Don't store the password as a session. It's not needed, nor is it safe. If you need the password later, do a SQL query using the username session as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['username'] = 'username';
//session_register("username");
$_SESSION['password'] = 'password';

you need to fetch the MySQL data and try using MySQLi
```